# Erro ao rodar projeto migrado do django 1.7 para django 1.10

Tags: django

Estou migrando um projeto feito em django 1.7 para o django 1.10, quando tento rodar o projeto recebo o erro:

> The view core.config.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object.
>   It returned None instead.

pelo que pude entender isso e por conta do reverse que foi descontinuado, a view que o erro se refere e a seguinte:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    dados={}
    if request.user.has_perm('admin'):
        return render(request, 'Template_Error.html',{'mensagem':"Você não possui permissão para Logar no sistema",'titulo':'Aviso!'})
    if request.user.has_perm('ava.view_professor'):
        return redirect(reverse(viewname='home_professor'))
    elif request.user.has_perm('ava.view_aluno'):
        return redirect(reverse(viewname='home_aluno'))
```

qual a forma correta de se fazer isso atualmente ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples) explica que basta passar o nome da view para o `redirect` que o `reverse` será usado.

```
def my_view(request):
...
return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

Comment: Obrigado, acredito que isso resolvera meu problema